# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[[4, 4, 4, 4], [2, 2, 2, 2], [6, 6, 6, 6], [8, 8, 8, 8], [8, 8, 8, 8]]'

Tags: python, string, matrix, casting

I want to convert this whole string into a 2d list of integer type.

```
b="[[31, 91, 80, 11], [50, 11, 20, 10], [22, 33, 11, 11], [10, 12, 33, 23], [8, 8, 8, 8]]"
```

I tried with the isdigit() function but it wouldn't work for the double digit strings as it was also splitting it into two parts like I need 31 as a single integer but isdigit() gives my output 3 1 separately.

```
for i in b:
    if (i.isdigit() == True):
```

Please help me to get out of this issue and solve my problem. so that it shows output as :

```
[[31, 91, 80, 11], [50, 11, 20, 10], [22, 33, 11, 11], [10, 12, 33, 23], [8, 8, 8, 8]]
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(b)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) from `ast`.

```
import ast
b="[[31, 91, 80, 11], [50, 11, 20, 10], [22, 33, 11, 11], [10, 12, 33, 23], [8, 8, 8, 8]]"
ast.literal_eval(b)
```

Output:

```
[[31, 91, 80, 11], [50, 11, 20, 10], [22, 33, 11, 11], [10, 12, 33, 23], [8, 8, 8, 8]]
```

Comment: You should mark an answer as "answered" if it helps you. green tick on left side below the upvote buttons. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers